# Creating a Polymorphic many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a polymorphic many to many relationship following [this](http://blog.dharanasoft.com/2011/09/06/polymorphic-many-to-many-associations-in-rails/) tutorial, but have came across a problem. When I try to access @friends.post, I get this:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/mattmoss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
Maybe IRB bug!
```

Here is the code that I am using to create my relationship:

In posts:

```
has_many :friends, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Friend"
has_many :taggings
```

In Postings:

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true
```

In Friends:

```
has_many :posts, :through => :postings
has_many :postings, :through => :posttable, :source_type => "Friend"
```

When I call friends.posts, I get the error listed above.

Comment: are you sure posts has many friends make sense ?

Comment: Hey, I had this same error a little while ago and it was because I hadn't set up the associations properly.  I think you need to rethink your associations. Describe to us how you'd like your association, we'll try and help

Comment: So it would be set up like tags, so one post can have many tags, but tags can also have many posts, comments, and more. I am looking for a setup just like the one in this post @Peege151 http://blog.dharanasoft.com/2011/09/06/polymorphic-many-to-many-associations-in-rails/

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way to do it. The user could select to post the post to their friends, as well as to a few other provided groups. @AnilMaurya, so it is almost acting like a tag for each post.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because when your Friend model has self referential relationship

remove :source_type => "Friend" from friend has_many :postings

```
has_many :posts, :through => :postings
has_many :postings, :through => :posttable
```